# High CPU usage with almost all the threads in BLOCKED STATE

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running a Java App in a tomcat container. The thread dump show most of the threads are in BLOCKED state. When I see the Heap usage I get the following output :

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 85983232 (82.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 652214272 (622.0MB)
   used     = 652214264 (621.9999923706055MB)
   free     = 8 (7.62939453125E-6MB)
   99.99999877340925% used
From Space:
   capacity = 31981568 (30.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 31981568 (30.5MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 31981568 (30.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 31981568 (30.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 1431830528 (1365.5MB)
   used     = 1281314952 (1221.957160949707MB)
   free     = 150515576 (143.54283905029297MB)
   89.48789168434325% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 71303168 (68.0MB)
   used     = 71127952 (67.83290100097656MB)
   free     = 175216 (0.1670989990234375MB)
   99.75426617790671% used

27815 interned Strings occupying 4203968 bytes.
```

Can someone help me debug. Is there something wrong with the configuration?

EDIT :

CPU Usage :

```
Cpu(s): 97.7%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  1.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3840320k total,  3741664k used,    98656k free,   103276k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,   160692k used,  4033608k free,   783984k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                         
23112 root      20   0 3562m 2.4g 8040 S  195 65.2 397:25.18 java
```

Comment: Are you using any form of synchronization among threads?

Comment: You say high CPU utilization but show nothing about that. Having a lot of threads blocking is normal for a server under load.

Comment: There is fair amount of synchronisation in the code. I have put the CPU usage stats, if that helps.

Comment: Can both survivor spaces be empty at the same time?

Comment: The Eden space should not be almost full for a long period (more than 5 seconds). If it is then the high CPU is caused by the garbage collector trying to free memory in the Eden space (Java really needs space there to do almost anything). Some memory tuning might help, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340208/3080094) for example.

Answer (score 0):

All your memory is being used so maybe there something going on there. You need a heap dump and to use a tool like Eclipse MemoryAnalizer to see if there are memory leaks. Maybe the application is just thrashing and the threads are blocking waiting for IO. That sounds likely.

But there might be other problems. Does the app use a database, messaging queue, FTP site, REST services, etc.? The JVM alone doesn't just go crazy and blow up like that, it's something you are trying to do that's causing it.

Comment: The app is connecting to databases. All the threads are BLOCKED on some kind of IO, like reading from redis, writing to log, writing to cassandra etc. Do threads get BLOCKED only on IO or does this point to something?

Comment: Did you try eclipse memory analyzer? It's really hard to tell what's going on with so little information or code. The memory analyzer will give you a hint while you have such high memory usage.

Comment: Threads may also be blocked waiting for other threads (synchronized code, pipes/queues, etc.). But yes, IO may cause a thread to be blocked waiting for data to arrive (input) or waiting for data to be accepted and transferred to wherever it's going (output). You can't run network code faster than your network connection (and the machine at the other end) will let it run; you can't save to a file faster than the disk can accept data... But blocked threads don't burn CPU until they wake up. Look at the ones that aren't blocked, or other processes.